# Is there any way to access private member variable of C++ complex number class?

Tags: c++

I am using the built in complex number class `std::complex` from the Standard C++ Library header. I applied a code in a HLS tools. The tool can not access a private member variable of that complex class. Is it possible to make it public or what can i do?

```
Error: /usrf01/prog/mentor/2015-16/RHELx86/QUESTA-SV-AFV_10.4c-5/questasim/gcc-4.7.4-linux_x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/complex(222): 
error: 'fpml::fixed_point<int, 16u, 15u> std::complex<fpml::fixed_point<int, 16u, 15u> >::_M_real' is private
```

Comment: Of course you can't access private members from outside the class, that's kind of the point of them being private.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real2

Comment: Also, what is "a HLS tools"? What are you really trying to do? Please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `#define private public`, seriously don't do this

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Answer (score 4):

The `std::complex` template is somewhat magic: You have explicit permission to reinterpret a complex number as an array of two scalars. More generally, the following is valid:

```
std::complex<float> a[10];

float* r = reinterpret_cast<float*>(a);

for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) std::cout << r[i] << '\n';
```

That is, you can treat an array of complex numbers like an array of twice as many real numbers. You can use this approach to access the elements of your complex number individually.

Do beware of the following constraint, though ([complex.numbers]p2):

> The effect of instantiating the template `complex` for any type other than `float`, `double`, or `long double` is
>   unspecified.

Comment: I did not know that! Where does it say that we have `explicit permission to reinterpret a complex number as an array of two scalars`?

Comment: @Pi [`[complex.numbers/4]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/complex.numbers#4)

Answer (score 4):

Just to be complete, another way to access the members is using the corresponding getters, for example like this

```
#include <complex>

int main()
{
   std::complex<float> c;
   c.real(1);
   c.imag(2);
   return c.real();
}
```